# How to detect if browser support iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there any way to detect if browser supports iframe?

Comment: Many of the mobile browsers do not support this. If you put an iframe in the page then the page behaves weirdly. Nokia S60 browsers (initial versions) do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this would work?

**HTML**:

```
<iframe ...>
  <script type="text/javascript">var iFramesSupported = false;</script>
</iframe>
```

Comment: jQuery? Seriously? How about `<iframe><script>iframeSupport=false</script></iframe>`?

Comment: In case you cannot or do not want to use inline scripts (e.g. CSP headers) - another option is to insert element with id and request it later in javascript. If element is _not_ present - iframe is supported.

`<iframe><div id="iframe-is-not-supported"></div></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

You can always test it...

```
<iframe src="user_can_see_iframes.php" width="0" height="0">
    <p>iframes not supported</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: If I put an iframe in the page then page gets redirected to the source URL of the iframe :(

Answer (score 1):

All major desktop browsers support iFrames.

If you mean in a mobile context, I managed to find this on google : http://johannburkard.de/blog/www/mobile/iframe-support-on-mobile-devices.html

Some older devices don't support iframes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy iframe and test its properties in javascript.